# Defining a polar coordinate system on a Euclidian space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, polar-coordinates, affine-geometry

A Cartesian coordinate system is formally defined on an affine Euclidian space by an ordered basis of orthogonal unit vectors and a coordinate origin, such that the coordinates of any point $P$ in the space are the components of the vector $\vec{OM}$ with respect to this basis. We can then intepret the coordinates as the signed perpendicular distances from the coordinate axes to $P$.

The Wikipedia article on [Euclidian spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Cartesian_coordinates) says this about defining *non-Cartesian* coordinate systems:

> Many other coordinates systems can be defined on a Euclidean space $E$ of dimension $n$, in the following way. Let $f$ be a homeomorphism (or, more often, a diffeomorphism) from a dense open subset of $E$ to an open subset of ${\displaystyle \mathbb {R} ^{n}.}$ The coordinates of a point $x$ of $E$ are the components of $f(x)$. The polar coordinate system (dimension $2$) and the spherical and cylindrical coordinate systems (dimension $3$) are defined this way.

I'm trying to determine how to define a polar coordinate system on a Euclidian space using the definition above, but can't decipher what it is getting at. I was wondering if someone could explain how we set up such a homeomorphism?

Thank you!

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates  we can build an extra z-dimension in t-parametric form :  

$$  \big(x= r (t) \cos \theta(t),\, y= r(t) \sin \theta(t),\ z(t)\, \big) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case of polar coordinates $\langle r, \theta\rangle$ for a point in $E=\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $f()$ here is the function that takes a point in Euclidean coordinates (i.e., $\langle x, y\rangle$) and produces polar coordinates for it; in other words $f(\langle x, y\rangle) = \langle\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\mathrm{atan2}(x,y)\rangle$. Here the $\mathrm{atan2}()$ function is the 'cs version' that's basically $\arctan(x/y)$ but extended in ways that recognize the signs of the coordinates, so that e.g. $\mathrm{atan2}(-x, -y)=\mathrm{atan2}(x,y)\pm\pi$.

Now, this function isn't 1-to-1 on all of $E$; in particular, it's not well-defined at the origin (and there's some fuzziness about coordinates on the x axis). However, $E-\{\langle x,0\rangle: x\geq 0\}$ is a dense, open subset of $E$, and $f()$ *is* defined on this dense open subset: it takes it to $\{\langle r, \theta\rangle: r\gt 0, 0\lt\theta\lt2\pi\}$, which is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ah, yes I think that works! Thanks a bunch!